# Camel - using custom jmsOperations: cannot be cast to org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate

Tags: apache-camel, spring-jms

I want to use a custom jmsOperations, when I try that  I get a class cast exception: cannot be cast to org.apache.camel.component.jms.**JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate**

Config :

```
<bean id="jmsErf" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
    <property name="jmsOperations" ref="myJmsTemplate" />   
    <property name="preserveMessageQos" value="true"/>
    <property name="explicitQosEnabled" value="false"/>
    <property name="testConnectionOnStartup" value="true"/>
    <!--property name="useMessageIDAsCorrelationID" value="true" / WARNING! Do not use this as we need to copy only in the beginning not everywhere -->
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="jpaTransactionManager" />
    <property name="transacted" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean name="myJmsTemplate" class="blabla.MyJmsTemplate">
<property name="connectionFactory">
    <bean class="jms.MQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="queueManagerName" value="${Queue.My.manager}" />
        <property name="throwOnInvalidMessageProperty" value="false" />
    </bean>
</property>
</bean>
```

Sample class I created

```
MyJmsTemplate extends org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate implements
        org.springframework.jms.core.JmsOperations { .. no code :)
```

Why I'm trying jmsOperations:
I just need to have original JMSPriority maintained. Yes I did try preserveQoS explicitQoS [various combinations of enablingetc.. it either sets all priority to 4; or priority remains zero despite setting eg=6 priority]. by creating my own jmsOperations and explictly transfering JMSPriority value.

Exception trace:

> Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateProducerException: Failed to
>   create Producer for endpoint:
>   Endpoint[jmsErf://queue:MQDEV.MYQ.ERROR]. Reason:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: blabla.MyJmsTemplate cannot be cast to
>   org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate  at
>   org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.testConnectionOnStartup(JmsProducer.java:458)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.doStart(JmsProducer.java:469)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:62)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doGetProducer(ProducerCache.java:387)
>     ... 115 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   bla.MyJmsTemplate cannot be cast to
>   org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate  at
>   org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.testConnectionOnStartup(JmsProducer.java:447)
>     ... 119 more

Can anyone point me to jmsOptions usage in camel?

Answer (score 0):

What Camel version do you use?

You should use a custom messageConverter if you want to map to/from JMS messages yourself.

And the JMSPriority ought to be preserved if you set preserveMessageQos=true.

Comment: camel version is 2.10.0. When I tested same flow with Spring integration implementation, I could see the JMSPriority in MQ (that rules out MQ or , any underlying api stripping out JMSPriority)

Comment: Are you using IBM WebSphere MQ? Is so make sure to set it in Java mode. There is some special option you need to set AFAIR.

Comment: Yes IBM MQ. I think we can rule-out special options as Spring Integration example is carrying the JMSPriority value that is set for the same set of IBM MQ queues.